# Banner stays over site header using SmartBanner

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile, smartbanner

I am using https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner/ for mobile visitors. Unfortunately, it places the banner ON TOP of my site header making the logo, search and menu buttons invisible.

Is there a way to make the SmartBanner push down the rest of my site?

My html is:

```
<body>
<div id="page" class="site" data-role="page">
  <!-- header -->
  <header id="masthead" class="site-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <div id="view-search" class="view-search ">
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
  </div>
```

I am using WPSmart for WordPress plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsmart-mobile/.

Comment: header with fixed position has `top: -1px` try overriding `.ui-header-fixed { top: 40px !important; }` or any value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use in your head

```
<meta name="smartbanner:disable-positioning" content="true">
```

After you can change in your own css the .smartbanner to the position you want

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and its currently working great for me. When the smartbanner is shown (line 131 in the js library), add in:

```
$('html').css('position', 'relative');
```

Then, all we need to do is position the smart banner. Go to line 136 + 140 and change "top :0" to:

```
top:'-'+ this.origHtmlMargin (this.bannerHeight*this.scale)
```

Comment: If this works for you too, could you please mark it as answered.